# Fill a php Multidimensional array in a html table

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array, html-table

I was given to fill this html table according to this multidimensional array.

[image: html table]

```
$eleves=array( 
    "Z200"=>array(
        "Salima",
        "module"=>array(
            "Math"=>array("note"=>10,"cof"=>5), 
            "Physique"=>array("note"=>10,"cof"=>2),
            "Langue"=>array("note"=>10,"cof"=>2)
        )
    ), 
    "Z103"=>array(
        "Ali",
        "module"=>array(
            "Math"=>array("note"=>2,"cof"=>5), 
            "Physique"=>array("note"=>5,"cof"=>2),
            "Langue"=>array("note"=>7,"cof"=>2)
        )
    ), 
    "Z109"=>array(
        "Hind", 
        "module"=>array(
            "Math"=>array("note"=>13,"cof"=>2), 
            "Physique"=>array("note"=>13,"cof"=>2),
            "Langue"=>array("note"=>11# ,"cof"=>2)
        )
    )
);
```

I tried the foreach loop. I succeed to fill the first head tables.

But when it comes to calculate the notes it's diffcult to call the values
Can you help me guys please ?

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain exactly what issue you had with the notes. "Difficult" isn't an error message or a problem description. Also if we have your existing code, we don't need to waste time rewriting the entire thing from nothing. See also [ask] and how to provide a [mre] of your issue. As you're new, the [tour] would also be beneficial. You can [edit] your post when you're ready.

Comment: Also it's unclear how the table data is supposed to map onto the raw array data. I don't see the text "Admis" or "Adjourne" anywhere in the raw data, for example. How do you calculate that output? Is there some formula you need to tell us about? It's also unclear how the numbers were calculated.

Comment: presumably `11#` is a mistake and that should not have the hash at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You need a first foreach to browse `$eleves`. For each student, you need a second foreach to add all grades and evaluate the mean.

```
function evalMoyenne ($grades) {
    $gradeSum = 0;
    $coeffCount = 0;

    foreach ( $grades as $subject => $grade ) {
        $gradeSum += $grade['note'] * $grade['cof'];
        $coeffCount += $grade['cof'];
    }

    return $gradeSum / $coeffCount;
}

foreach ( $eleves as $matricule => $row ) {
    $moyenne = evalMoyenne( $row['module'] );
    echo "<td>$matricule</td>"
    . '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>'
    . '<td>' . $moyenne . '</td>'
}
```

Usually, if you have an array in an array, you need a `foreach` in a `foreach`. As an alternative, if there are a fixed subject count, you could also hardcode the meaning calculation:

```
$gradeSum = $row['module']['Math']['note'] * $row['module']['Math']['cof']
    + $row['module']['Physique']['note'] * $row['module']['Physique']['cof']
    + $row['module']['Langue']['note'] * $row['module']['Langue']['cof']
$cofSum = $row['module']['Math']['cof'] + $row['module']['Physique']['cof'] + $row['module']['Langue']['cof'];
$moyenne = $gradeSum / $cofSum;
```

Comment: Thanks i already solved it and with the Same method as yours
I just added the decision "ajourné" or "admis".          .  $moyenne= ($note)/($mod["Math"]["cof"]+ $mod["Physique"]["cof"] + $mod["Langue"]["cof"]) ;
if($moyenne>=10){
  $decision="Admis" ;
}
else $decision="Ajourné" ;
   echo "<TR><TD>$clef </TD><TD>".$val[0]."</TD><TD>$moyenne</TD><TD>$decision</TD></TR>\n";
    }